# If ${x_n}$ is a Cauchy sequence in a bounded set $S$, then ${f(x_n)}$ is a Cauchy sequence implies that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $S$.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f$ is a function and $S$ is a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$.  I want to prove that

if ${x_n}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $S$, then ${f(x_n)}$ is a Cauchy sequence

implies that

$f$ is uniformly continuous on $S$.

Answer (score 2):

Let's prove it by contradiction.

If $f$ were not uniformly continuous, then we would have a number $\delta > 0$ and two sequences $x_n$ and $y_n$ such that $|x_n-y_n| \leq \frac{1}{n}$ and $|f(x_n)-f(y_n)| \geq \delta$.

Since $S$ is bounded, we can find a subsequence $x_{n_k}$ with a limit $l$. It's easy to see that also $y_{n_k}$ goes to $l$.

Here comes the tricky part, both $(x_{n_k})_k$ and $(y_{n_k})_k$ are Cauchy sequence, but this does not help us. Is there a "new" sequence that can do that?

Yes, there is. Consider the sequence $x_{n_1},y_{n_1},x_{n_2},y_{n_2},\ldots$

Can you finish from here?

Comment: How did you get that since $S$ is bounded there is a subsequence going to some $l$?

Comment: @E2R0NS [Bolzano–Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem)

Comment: @LucaMac Why $1/n$?

Comment: @E2R0NS The assumption that $|x_n - y_n| \le \frac{1}{n}$ can be replaced by $x_n - y_n \to 0$. Indeed, $1/n$ could also be replaced by any null-convergent sequence.